# Call function present inside php class?

Tags: php, rss

```
<?php
    class MxitRSS {
        function MxitRSS($rsslink,$noofposts = 3)
        {
            //'http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=h&output=rss'
            if($rsslink != NULL)
            {
                $rss = new DOMDocument();
                $rss->load($rsslink);
                $feed = array();
                foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
                    $item = array ( 
                        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                    );
                   array_push($feed, $item);
                }

                for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
                    $randomnum= rand(5, 20);
                    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
                    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
                    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
                    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
                    echo '<strong>'.$title.'</strong><br />';
                    echo '<i>Posted on '.$date.'</i>';
                    echo '<br/><br/>'.$description.'<br/>';
                    echo '<br/><a href=index.php?page=article&id='.$randomnum.'><i>read more</i></a><br/>';
                }
            } else {  }
        }
    }
?>
```

**Calling function**

```
<?php
    include('rss.php');
    $this -> MxitRSS('http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=h&output=rss',3);
?>
```

I am trying to call the above function on another page, however it isn't working. I am new to php. Is this fine what I am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct way to use classes is to instantiate it first. but since in your case classname is equal to methodname, your method is a contructor and will run once the class instantiated. (in case your php is lower than 5.3. this use is deprecated and __construct is the new and correct way to name a constructor)

```
$myClass = new MxitRSS('http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=h&output=rss',3);
```

Comment: try changing `function MxitRSS($rsslink,$noofposts = 3)` to `function __construct($rsslink,$noofposts = 3)`

Comment: also i advise you to put error_reporting(E_ALL); and display_errors(1); at the top of your php page to better diagnose the problem.

Comment: is DOMDocument class defined? by that i mean do you have php-xml installed on your server?

Comment: php-xml is installed as i am able to generate feed if i just call the code without it being in a function

Comment: did you try the other comments about error reporting and __constructor?

Comment: Hey thanks it works now there was some issue in my code

Answer (score 0):

Actually, because you the class has the same name as the function, the function will act as a constructor,  <strike>so Volkan Ulukuts answer will call the function twice, once without the URL and once with. I don't think you want that.</strike>

Below should do what you want.

```
<?php
   include('rss.php');
   new MxitRSS('http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=h&output=rss',3);
?>
```

Something interesting to note is that if you changed the name of the "MxitRSS" function to "__construct" it would work exactly the same but it would make things a little clearer IMO.